# python: find out if an array of objects meets certain criteria

Tags: python, json, filter

I have a list of objects like

```
[{'type' :'car', 'color' : 'red', 'engine' : 'diesel'}, {'type' : 'truck'...}
```

now i am looking for python 3 based approach that somehow allows me to define filters returning true or false.
In that array is there a red truck and a car having diesel engine?
Anyone got an idea where to start looking?

Basically I want to create a service that allows you to match rules against such lists. Like the user can define some filter that i apply to the list returning true or false.

like "color=red and engine=diesel"...something like what u can do in prolog. I looked at pyke but it seems to be too complex

Comment: have you tried using a for loop? why doesn't that work?

Comment: You might start with the `filter` function.

Comment: I frankly don't understand the downvotes. Yes, it's a simple question, but it's not particularly bad.

Comment: @xaav I agree, they haven't tried anything but that doesn't deserve `-5`

Comment: This isn't about JSON, unless you are asking how to deserialize that string.

Comment: i think my question was not clear. I am looking for something like a rule engine. That filter stuff i know. Basically I want to create a service that u can send a rule to and it returns if that rule applied to that array will return true or false. SO it should be customizable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given:

```
>>> inv=[{'type' :'car', 'color' : 'red', 'engine' : 'diesel'}, {'type' : 'truck','color':'red','engine':'diesel'}, {'type':'bike','color':'red','engine':None}]
```

Since you have a list of dictionaries, construct a dict that contains what you want to filter on:

```
>>> fo={'color':'red', 'type':'car'}
```

And then filter on that with either `all` for `and` between the elements or `any` for `or`:

```
>>> [d for d in inv if all(d[e]==fo[e] for e in fo if e in d)] 
[{'color': 'red', 'engine': 'diesel', 'type': 'car'}]
```

If you prefer the filter function, same approach:

```
>>> fo={'engine': 'diesel'}
>>> filter(lambda d: all(d[e]==fo[e] for e in fo if e in d), inv)
[{'color': 'red', 'engine': 'diesel', 'type': 'car'}, {'color': 'red', 'engine': 'diesel', 'type': 'truck'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can build a list comprehension selecting only the elements that respect intended conditions:

```
my_objects = [{'type' :'car', 'color' : 'red', 'engine' : 'diesel'}]

print([x for x in my_objects if x['type'] == 'car' and x['color'] == 'red'])
```

Comment: That's probably the best answer. I wonder how the performance compares to mine.

Comment: Why don't you edit your question then and explain exactly what you want. That comment isn't very clear either.

Comment: that one looks promising!

Comment: okay, was too fast... that is ot doing what i want... i think i might need to go for regex

Answer (score 0):

Just create a `function` using a `for-loop`:

```
def check(lst, vehicle, val):
    for d in lst:
        if d["type"] == vehicle:
            return val in d.values()
    return False
```

and we can do some tests:

```
>>> check([{'type' :'car', 'color' : 'red', 'engine' : 'diesel'}], "car", "red")
True
>>> check([{'type' :'car', 'color' : 'red', 'engine' : 'diesel'}], "car", "blue")
False
>>> check([{'type' :'car', 'color' : 'red', 'engine' : 'diesel'}], "car", "diesel")
True
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer a list comprehension:

```
l = [{'type' :'car', 'color' : 'red', 'engine' : 'diesel'}, {'type' : 'truck'...}
d = [d for d in l if (key, value) in d.items() and (key, value) in d.items()]
```